# Extracting p-value from anova table in R

Tags: r, vector, anova

**
The preceding steps are as such:

```
a <- rnorm(100, mean=2, sd=3)
response <- a * 1.5 + rnorm(100, mean=0, sd=1)
model <- lm(response ~ a)
vartest <- anova(model)
```

I would like to extract the p-value **into a vector** associated with the a coefficient, which is a value that will be < 2.2e-16.

The code I have is:

```
vartest[1,5]
[1] 1.002182e-63
```

in which `vartest` produces the following variance table. 
I would like to know if I'm doing it wrong, or is there an alternative to this method, for extracting the value into a vector?

[image]

Comment: i have clarified the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can directly extract with the name of the column with either `[[` or `$`

```
out <- vartest[["Pr(>F)"]][1]
is.vector(out)
#[1] TRUE
```

-checking with OP's approach

```
identical(out, vartest[1,5])
#[1] TRUE
```

---

We could check the structure of the object with `str`

```
str(vartest)
```

and this would give an idea about how to extract the components

Comment: and just to confirm, the result will be considered a vector?

Comment: @aislinx yes, it is a vector.  you can check wiht `is.vector`